# quickfix/j SessionSettings loads only the last session from file config

Tags: java, quickfix, fix-protocol, quickfixj

When I try to call the constructor of SessionSettings with the URL of the config file, it loads only the last session exists in the file.

I have tried print what my code is reading from the config file but I got this:

```
[DEFAULT]
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
ReconnectInterval=5
TargetCompID=Server
SenderCompID=Client
DataDictionary=C:\config\FIX42.xml
HeartBtInt=30
FileStorePath=C:\logsBadisInitiatorStore
UseDataDictionary=Y
FileLogPath=C:\logsBadisInitiator
[SESSION]
StartTime=00:00:00
ConnectionType=acceptor
EndTime=23:59:59
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SocketAcceptPort=9878
TargetCompID=server1
SessionName=badisAcc289
SenderCompID=client1
SocketAcceptAddress=localhost
UseDataDictionary=N
```

But my config file contains more than that:

```
[default]
FileStorePath=data
SenderCompID=Client
TargetCompID=Server
FileLogPath=C:\logsBadisInitiator
StartTime=00:00:00 
EndTime=23:59:59
HeartBtInt=30
ReconnectInterval=5
UseDataDictionary=Y
DataDictionary=C:\config\FIX42.xml
FileStorePath=C:\logsBadisInitiatorStore

[session] 
SessionName=badisAcc2
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=client1
TargetCompID=server1
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=9878
SocketAcceptAddress=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
UseDataDictionary=N

[session] 
SessionName=test211
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=client1
TargetCompID=server1
ConnectionType=initiator
SocketConnectPort=9878
SocketConnectHost=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
UseDataDictionary=N

[session] 
SessionName=badisAcc3
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=client1
TargetCompID=server1
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=9878
SocketAcceptAddress=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
UseDataDictionary=N

[session] 
SessionName=badisAcc4
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=client1
TargetCompID=server1
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=9878
SocketAcceptAddress=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
UseDataDictionary=N

[session] 
SessionName=badisAcc289
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=client1
TargetCompID=server1
ConnectionType=acceptor
SocketAcceptPort=9878
SocketAcceptAddress=localhost
StartTime=00:00:00
EndTime=23:59:59
UseDataDictionary=N
```

This is the code that I wrote to load the sessionSettings:

```
String URLConfigFile="c:/config/initiatorSettings.txt";

sessionSettings = new SessionSettings(URLConfigFile);

System.out.println("sessionSettings tostring "+sessionSettings.toString());
```

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Why do you have an acceptor defined in a file called "initiatorSettings.txt"?  (And why "txt" and not "cfg"?)

Comment: true, I will fix that thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Root cause**
One session's config is clobbering the other, because both sessions have the same SessionID.

Both of your sessions have the same SessionID, which is constructed from BeginString/SenderCompID/TargetCompID (and sometimes other fields).

The SessionSetting is actually a hash of individual dictionaries for each session, keyed by SessionID.  Since your sessions have the same SessionID, they're clobbering each other.

**Your config also has a logical problem**

If you want these two sessions to talk to each other, then the Sender/Target values should be opposite, e.g.

```
[session] 
SessionName=badisAcc2
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=server1
TargetCompID=client1
ConnectionType=acceptor
...

[session] 
SessionName=test211
BeginString=FIX.4.2
SenderCompID=client1
TargetCompID=server1
ConnectionType=initiator
...
```

Comment: All sessions should have unique BeginString/SenderCompID/TargetCompID tuples.